# Angular ng-selected not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the selected tab so when a user tries to edit his or her profile the data is preset to the current data. It creates a list just doesnt create the selected. Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

```
<b>Education:</b> <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="currentUser.education">
            <option ng-repeat="education in educations" value = "{{education.educationId}}" 
            ng-selected ="{{education.educationName == currentUser.educationName}}">{{education.educationName}}</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Will you answer control.

Comment: if so please accept/vote it